# How can the Panels IPE "add content" modal be customized?

Tags: 7, panels

I have a content type rendered via Panels IPE (In Place Editor) which allows authenticated users to customize the layout of their node. When users click to "add content" I would like to be able to control what appears in the modal dialogue. By default it is not very user friendly:

[image]

Ideally I would like to be able to choose what can be added, for example only "nodes", or only "views" and "widgets". I'm not sure where this can be changed or if a module exists that does this already. The only module I have found that attempts to do this is [Panopoly Magic](https://drupal.org/project/panopoly_magic) which requires an entire suite of modules called Panopoly to be installed. I don't need the majority of the functionality that Panopoly adds and hence I don't think it is a very light solution. Here is the result that can be achieved:

[image]

Is there a way the IPE add content modal can be customized?

Answer (score 2):

You can do that for all panels pages from
admin/structure/panels/settings/panel-page

[image]

Also if you use panelizer you can customize what appear in IPE for every content type.
admin/structure/types/manage/[content-type]/panelizer

Also you can install [panopoly_magic](https://www.drupal.org/project/panopoly_magic) module without other panopoly features, only the module "[panopoly_magic.info](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/panopoly_magic/tree/panopoly_magic.info)" since it does not deponent on any thing in panopoly distribution.